# Magento 2.4.1 setup:install problem : "the default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again."

Tags: installation, composer, magento2.4.1

I downloaded `magento 2-2.4.1.zip`. Unzipped it to `/var/www/html/magento24/` - my local folder for local domain http://magento24.local configured by `nginx on ubuntu20.04`.

I had done composer update or install and next use this command:

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://magento24.local \
 --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento24 --db-user=user24 --db-password=1234 \
 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
 --admin-user=admin --admin-password=test1234 --language=en_US \
 --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

This stopped on step 4:

```
[Progress: 4 / 818]
Installing database schema:

In WebsiteRepository.php line 159:
                                                                     
  The default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again.
```

I tried different way. To download magento2.4.1 by composer from magento repository:

```
php /bin/composer1/composer.phar create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.1 .
```

But this first throw problems with composer version (**first i use coimposer 2.0.x, next uses 1.0.0alpha - different errors php7.3 and php7.1 fpm**)

Comment: just wipe the dir and reinstall: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30696#issuecomment-728780497 make sure you install elasticsearch.

Answer (score 45):

It appears that this error might appear when a MySQL database is empty, but the `env.php` file is present. (Possibly because you had setup Magento, but for some reason, database was deleted.)

To fix this you can add `--cleanup-database` flag to `setup:install` command (For me, it went ok only after the second try.), or delete the `env.php` file indeed, which I don't recommend.

Ex.

```
php bin/magento setup:install \
      --base-url=http://www.magento.lan \
      --db-host=localhost \
      --db-name=db_magento \
      --db-user=magento \
      --db-password=magento@123 \
      --admin-firstname=magento \
      --admin-lastname=Admin \
      --admin-email=magento@admin.com \
      --admin-user=magento \
      --admin-password=magento@123 \
      --language=en_US \
      --currency=USD \
      --timezone=America/Chicago \
      --use-rewrites=1 --cleanup-database
```

Comment: I confirm that this problem occurs if you have an empty database and env.php exists.

Answer (score 14):

I was changing a db and removing env.php helped to get rid of the error for me.

Comment: Thank you, deleting the previous app/etc/env.php fixed the problem

Answer (score 7):

=>>>   DELETE env.php file ..its work

After run this command

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento4" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento4" --db-user="root" --db-password= --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --admin-firstname="admin12" --admin-lastname="user" --admin-email="admin12@example.com" --backend-frontname="admin"

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to to work this:

Use composer version 1.9.0:

**1. Instal composer 1.9. Or You can downgrade it.**

- cd /var/www/html/mag241/
- php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer',
  'composer-setup.php');"
- sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/bin/composer19
  --version=1.9.0

**2. Use composer 1.9 to get magento2.4.1.**

- php /bin/composer19/composer.phar create-project
  --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.4.1 .

**3. Run bin/magento setup:install with Your database adres login and url**

- php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://magento24.local/
  --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento24 --db-user=user24 --db-password=1234 --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com --elasticsearch-port=9200

Answer (score 1):

It occurs if default website's data is not found which is stored in [store_website]. That means Magento site can't connect to database or database tables. For my case, I installed Magento with "m_" prefix for tables, then I changed its database whose tables doesn't have any prefix. So, to fix this issue, I modified:

`'table_prefix' => 'm_'` to `'table_prefix' => ''` in app/etc/env.php

Answer (score 0):

Its a table prefix mentioned in env.php, that works for me after update.

Thanks
Ravi P

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while trying to run the integration tests,

For those who are getting this error after trying to run the integration tests. I faced this issue since in one of my local modules I was using some classes as a dependency injection but Magento couldn't find that class so I kept getting that error.

It is fixed for me just by using Proxy instead of that class directly as a dependency injection.

Comment: I believe your issue was a different case. Yes, proxies solvie issues with command lines that use dependency injections that connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the `table_prefix` not declared in my `env.php` and the <s>idiot</s> person who initially created the db I was using, created the db with prefixes.