# when creating database showing error The default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://oxygen.local --db-host=localhost --db-name=oxygen –db-user=root --db-password=Root@123 --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=web --admin-email=admin123@gmail.com.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin@123 --language=en_US --currency=INR --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

[image]

Comment: can you please specify which Magento version you are trying to install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.4.1 setup:install problem : "the default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again."](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328568/magento-2-4-1-setupinstall-problem-the-default-website-isnt-defined-set-th)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below command line below to install Magento think this will help you,

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://oxygen.local" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="oxygen" --db-user="root" --db-password="Root@123" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="web" --admin-email="admin-email=admin123@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine="elasticsearch7" --elasticsearch-host="localhost" --elasticsearch-port="9200"
```